# select a td by table class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-table

I've searched online for the answer but

```
$(".classname tbody tr td") or $("table.classname tbody tr td")
```

don't work, I have got a table with only a class and I need to operate on `td`s etc.

the only reason why it don't work is probably the name of the class which is :`table name name-surname`.

the html is like this

```
<div class="tab">
  <table class="table name name-surname">
     <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>name</td>
          <td>surname</td>
        </tr>
     </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

is this the real problem or i'm missing something?
there's a way to go around it?
i can't add an id or change the name of the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always write your selector as this `.table.name.name-surname tbody tr td`

```js
$(".table.name.name-surname tbody tr td").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <table class="table name name-surname">
    <tbody>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>surname</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Inorder for `$(".classname tbody tr td")`  or `$("table.classname tbody tr td")`  to work, the tablw should have a class called `classname`

```js
console.log($(".classname tbody tr td"));
console.log($("table.classname tbody tr td"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <table class="table name name-surname classname">
    <tbody>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>surname</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use one of your table class like `$(".table")` or if you want to use multiple class connect them by `dot` like this: `$('.table.name.name-surname tbody tr td')`

Here is working sample:

```js
$(".table tbody tr td").each(function(itm,el) {
   console.log(el);
});

$('.table.name.name-surname tbody tr td').each(function(itm,el) {
   console.log(el);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">
        <table class="table name name-surname">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>name</td>
                    <td>surname</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: sorry i miswrite the html, in the actual code the trs are present

Comment: @userone Ok I updated my answer based on your update. you can chain the class selector by dot like this: table.name.name-surname or just use one of them like: .table

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "." for all the classes [.table.name.name-surname] and for the element tags, just their names [tbody td]
Also, you don't have tr element in your html.

```js
console.log($(".table.name.name-surname tbody td"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<div class="tab">
  <table class="table name name-surname">
    <tbody>
      <td>name</td>
      <td>surname</td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```